# Binning axis of heatmap aggregating by maximum in vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

I am trying to do a binning operation over one of the axis of a heatmap, and trying to retain the maximum value to the set the colour in that bin.

Consider the following example

```json
{
  "data": {"name": "my_data"},
  "mark": "rect",
  "encoding": {
    "color": {
      "type": "quantitative",
      "field": "z"
    },
    "tooltip": [{"type": "quantitative", "field": "z"},
    {"type": "ordinal", "field": "y"},
    {"type": "ordinal", "field": "x"}],
    "x": {
      "type": "ordinal",
      "field": "x"
    },
    "y": {
      "type": "ordinal",
      "field": "y"
    }
  },
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.8.1.json",
  "datasets": {
    "my_data": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 0, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 1, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 1, "y": 1, "z": 1},
      {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 2, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 3, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 3, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 4, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 4, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 5, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 5, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 6, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 6, "y": 1, "z": 0}]
  }
}
```

which shows something like:

[image: original]

Now, I try to aggregate the x axis by adding `{"color": {"aggregate": "max"}}` and `{"x": {"bin": {"step": 2}}`, and I get the following:

[image: binned-2]

Now, for other binning values (e.g. "step": 3), the hot-spot disappears:

[image: binned-3]

What am I getting wrong?

EDIT: Also, setting the aggregator to `mean`, still leaves me with the same values (instead of at least showing 0.5 in the first case), while `count` always returns 1.

EDIT2: While @jakevdp's solution worked for the example above, I still see the same problem when the 1-hot value is set at the boundaries of the bin, for example with:

```json
"my_data": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 1},
      {"x": 0, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 1, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 1, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 2, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 3, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 3, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 4, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 4, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 5, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 5, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 6, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 6, "y": 1, "z": 0}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you've declared the `x` and `y` fields in the tooltip, so all binnings are grouped by those values. The result is that in each bin you have multiple squares plotted on top of each other, one for each unbinned x value.

The solution is to avoid specifying unbinned fields in the tooltip:

```json
{
  "data": {"name": "my_data"},
  "mark": "rect",
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "z", "aggregate": "max"},
    "tooltip": [{"type": "quantitative", "field": "z"}],
    "x": {"type": "ordinal", "field": "x", "bin": {"step": 3}},
    "y": {"type": "ordinal", "field": "y"}
  },
  "datasets": {
    "my_data": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 0, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 1, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 1, "y": 1, "z": 1},
      {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 2, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 3, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 3, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 4, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 4, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 5, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 5, "y": 1, "z": 0},
      {"x": 6, "y": 0, "z": 0},
      {"x": 6, "y": 1, "z": 0}
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! There still seems to be a problem when x=1 for x at the limits of the bin (say x=0 or x=3 when step is 3, or x=0/2/4 when step is 2). Any idea why?  (NB: this is a minimal example of a larger plot in which I am experiencing this issue of values disappearing and just removing the tooltip didn't do the trick for me.)

Comment: OK, I've found it. The culprit was indeed the tooltip, and as it seems, I need to add "aggregate": "max" to it as well. Would you mind updating your answer with that piece of information? I will then mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks for pointing me out in the right direction!

Comment: More info on tooltips over aggregated fields here: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5992.

Comment: Argh, I cannot edit my first comment, but where it says "a problem when x=1 for x...", it should say "a problem when z=1 for x..."